# Constructor implicitly deleted

Tags: c++, constructor

The related code is listed below, you could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/3GH8zD.
I could solve the complier compile error indeed.But i am not completely clear about the reason lie behind it.I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    A(int x = 1): x(x) {} // user-defined default constructor
};

struct F : public A
{
    int& ref; // reference member
    const int c; // const member
    // F::F() is implicitly defined as deleted
};

int main()
{
  F f; // compile error
}
```

Compiler compliains:

```
Could not execute the program

Compiler returned: 1

Compiler stderr

<source>:10:15: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]

   10 |         const int; // const member

      |               ^~~

<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:16:9: error: use of deleted function 'F::F()'

   16 |       F f; // compile error

      |         ^

<source>:7:12: note: 'F::F()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

    7 |     struct F : public A

      |            ^

<source>:7:12: error: uninitialized reference member in 'struct F'

<source>:9:14: note: 'int& F::ref' should be initialized

    9 |         int& ref; // reference member

      |              ^~~
```

The right code may be:

```
struct F
{
    int& ref = x; // reference member
    const int c = 1; // const member
    // F::F() is implicitly defined as deleted
};
```

Comment: The class `A` is unrelated to the issue. The problem is that you must initialize reference members explicitly. The compiler can't do it automatically for you.

Comment: In case of errors for which you are not sure what they mean or why they occur it is sometimes helpful to compile it with a different compiler, to check how they report that error. `clang` e.g. reports it that way `default constructor of 'F' is implicitly deleted because field 'ref' of reference type 'int &' would not be initialized`, so `clang` combines the `error: uninitialized reference member in 'struct F'` and the `'F::F()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class member `int& ref` needs to be *bound* to an `int` when an object of type `F` is created.

A compiler-generated default constructor would not know how to bind it, so the compiler merely deletes the default constructor.

In the second snippet you explicitly set the member. (You can do that from C++11).

Comment: Quote:"The class member int& ref needs to be bound to an int when an object of type F is created."Could you explain that more in detail?Why dossn't the compiler allow the bind operation after an object of type F is created?I mean do the assignment operation after the constrution.

Comment: @John: Because that would be too late. It needs to be bound *during* the creation of an object. You can't even bind references in the constructor body for example.

Comment: @John, C++ references work that way in general. You can't rebind them or latebind them.

Comment: @John a reference must be bound during its initialization only, it can't be rebound afterward. That is why `F::ref` can't be assigned after an `F` object is constructed.

Comment: @Bathsheba But, "int& ref = x; " compiles successfully indeed.It's ok to bind  references in the constructor body. You could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/qCEJYx.

Comment: @John: Where exactly are you purportedly binding the reference in the constructor body (i.e. the bit between `{` and `}`) in that example?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau & chris Quote:"it can't be rebound afterward.". What are the reasons lie behind?

Comment: @John That's not the constructor body. That is a default initializer.

Comment: @John "*What are the reasons lie behind?*" - because that is just the way the standard defines it. If a reference could be rebound after being initialized, it would be no different than a raw pointer.

Comment: @John, According to the Design and Evolution book, "I had in the past been bitten by Algol68 references where `r1=r2` can either assign through `r1` to the object referred to or assign a new reference value to `r1` (re-binding `r1`) depending on the type of `r2`. I wanted to avoid such problems in C++." `std::reference_wrapper` exists if you want a rebindable version, but it's rather wordy, and of course pointers bring null with them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau & chris Thank you for the clarification.You make it clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the **Deleted implicitly-declared default constructor** section in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). It explains under which circumstances the default constructor is deleted:

> - T has a member of reference type without a default initializer. (since C++11)
> - T has a const member without user-defined default constructor or a default member initializer (since C++11).

That is, if you don't default initialize your const and reference member variables, the constructor will be deleted and it also explains why your second attempt "worked". In fact, it doesn't work until you make `F` inherit from `A` (I guess this was your intention). Otherwise, you can't assign `A::x` to `F::ref`.

**Note:** Even though `F::ref=A::x` is allowed, there is no point in doing that since `F` already has access to `A::x` due to inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.Quote: "In fact, it doesn't work until you make F inherit from A (I guess this was your intention). Otherwise, you can't assign A::x to F::ref.".Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John Well, if you don't inherit from `A` then there is no `x` around that `F` could see. In this case you compiler will show you an error like this: `error: 'x' was not declared in this scope`.

Answer (score 2):

To try to build on @Bathsheba answer.

Let's first understand what a reference is. A reference is essentially a pointer that *can't be null* this makes them very tricky to initialize.

Let's look at your second class:

```
struct F : public A
{
    int& ref; // reference member
    const int c; // const member
    // F::F() is implicitly defined as deleted
};
```

If instead of defining it as `int& ref;` we define it as `int ref;` the compiler will say, I have no idea what ref is supoosed to be, so I'll stick some random value into it and be done. And so the default constructor just does `ref = /*some num*/;`

Let's say it was a pointer instead, i.e `int* ref;` Once again, the default constructor needs to initialize it to a value, for pointers the most logical value for default initialization is `nullptr` and so we get `int* ref = nullptr;`

But what if it is a reference? i.e `int& ref;`. We can;t initialize the variable to a number, because it is not a number it's a reference "i.e a pointer" to a number. But references can't be null so we can;t use `nullptr` either. So there is no valid default value initialization for the reference. The only reasonable thing is then to delete the default constructor because there does not exist any default value we can use to initialize one of its members.

Comment: "so I'll stick 0 into it an be done." - no it doesn't do that unless you initialise the object using `{}` syntax.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that's not part of the spec (some compilers let you specify that you want to default initialize integers to 0 unless otherwise specified, but it's not part of the standard), my bad.

Comment: @Makogan Quote:"We can't initialize the variable to a number, because it is not a number it's a reference "i.e a pointer" to a number. " What do you mean by "it's a reference "i.e a pointer" to a number."? I wonder that wether `references` are internally implemented as `pointers` by compiler.Could i think in that way?

Comment: References are just pointers that cannot be null.  That's what I mean.